# Can I use Open Office on my new MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, gatekeeper, open-office

I just downloaded Open Office to my Mac Book Air and installed it. When I tried to open it a message came up saying it's developed by an unidentified source and my computer settings only allow installation of programs from Mac App Store or identified developers. I don't know anything about code. What can I do?

Comment: Is the OS Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

You have just seen [GateKeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290) in action.

If you are confident you downloaded a safe copy of the program, you can tell your Mac to "trust" that program and let it past the gate.

- Right click on the icon
- Select Open
- Read the dialog and agree or disagree to let that program run

The linked article above goes into much detail on GateKeeper and I would scan it and review the steps above. If you find a lot of software you need triggers the warning, you could relax the settings, but I prefer to keep them at the defaults as I like to know when new code runs on my Mac.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I downloaded it from http://www.openoffice.org/sv/get/ How can I be sure it's safe?

Comment: As with any other piece of software you have to trust the developers. What you can do is to validate your download against a checksum. I suppose that you've downloaded `OOo_3.3.0_MacOS_x86_install_sv.dmg`. Its MD5 checksum is `869e4b23022a7d318e3668003ea33a5c` (from http://www.openoffice.org/download/legacy/md5sums/3.3.0_md5sums.txt). Open Terminal and type either `md5 ~/Downloads/OOo_3.3.0_MacOS_x86_install_sv.dmg` or `md5sum ~/Downloads/OOo_3.3.0_MacOS_x86_install_sv.dmg` (not sure of the top off my head). If the number you get coincides with the MD5 checksum above your download is OK.